# Reactjs: Stop rerendering on a particular state change with shouldComponentUpdate()

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple setState in my component onload. My page is re-rendering on click of dropdown values, because on-click I'm storing those values via `setState`.

Here to stop re-rendering on click, I'm using the below code.

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false
}
```

Now because of the above function, My values are not storing in state on page load. Is there anything I need to do extra ?

Comment: You're effectively breaking your component by always returning `false` from `shouldComponentUpdate`. More information is needed to understand what you're trying to do. Please [edit] to provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: If you always return `false`, then your component will basically never update.

Answer (score 12):

You states don't show a change in your component, because it doesn't rereder at all, since you have returned `false` from the `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

If you want to restrict rendering on particular state change then just check for that state and return false else return true like

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
     if(this.state.dropdownVal != nextState.dropdownval) {
          return false
     }
     return true
}
```

However its not such a bad thing to rerender because React rendering process is very efficient and you would want to show the updated state in the DOM more often then not.

Comment: yes i agree , but it could become in handy for react owl carousel , it re-render on every change in state , and this could be in efficient so your code could help a lot in those situations a like

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `shouldComponentUpdate()` like

```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return !Immutable.is(this.state.synergy, nextState.synergy)
 }
```

Comment: Where does the OP say anything about using immutable.js, or having a property named `synergy`?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments. I got it solved with the help of this url https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Comment: @TomFenech : based on the answer OP got the idea how to set true and false , and BTW OP didn't say anything so I just give him an example

Answer (score 0):

The answer: you need to re-render. There's nothing wrong with this. However, if you have a lot of logic built in to your render statements (which you shouldn't do, logic should be happening in your containers) this can be cumbersome. Use element key's efficiently, and there's nothing wrong with re-rendering. You're looking for a way to subvert the design patterns of React, when you should instead be conforming in MOST cases.

Comment: Great answer! But when you say containers, what do you mean? Thanks.