# How do I cancel a `this.setState`?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

So I know that setting state in React is asynchronous and all and we set state like this:

```
this.setState(previousState => {
  return { /* some new state that uses `previousState` */ }
});
```

So my question is: **How can I cancel a `this.setState`?** Let's say I use `previousState` to determine that I don't need to render an update. How can I cancel the `setState` and tell React not to re-render anything.

```
this.setState(previousState => {
  if (/* previousState is fine */) {
    // tell react not to do anything
  } else {
    return { /* some new state */ }
  }
});
```

Comment: How would you determine that you don't need another update? Do you mean if the state hasn't changed?

Comment: Why call `this.setState()` in the first place? Sounds like all you need to do is check `this.state`, then *not* call `this.setState()`

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle is what you need. Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521391/reactjs-stop-rerendering-on-a-particular-state-change-with-shouldcomponentupdat/44522755#44522755

Comment: Also note that setting the state to exactly what it previously was shouldn't cause a `render()` call anyway; one of the points of creating React in the first place was to avoid unnecessary GUI updates, afaik.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question here, but newer React 16 allows you to cancel a `setState`.

> Minor changes to setState behavior:
>
> - Calling `setState` with `null` no longer triggers an update. This allows you to decide in an updater function if you want to re-render.
> - Calling `setState` directly in render always causes an update. This was not previously the case. Regardless, you should not be calling `setState` from render.
> - `setState` callback (second argument) now fires immediately after `componentDidMount` / `componentDidUpdate` instead of after all components have rendered.

[source](https://github.com/facebook/react/releases/tag/v16.0.0)

---

The important distinction between returning `null` and returning `previousState` is that returning `null` does what like `PureComponent` does and prevents a the `render` method from being called at all.

Starting from React 16, calling `setState` always makes the `render` method fire even if you return `previousState`.

---

To @`bennygenel`'s point though, you should use `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent re-renders.

---

**Update:** As of React 16.8, if you're using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) (this is *unrelated to class components*), then returning previous state from `useState` *does*, in fact, prevent the re-render altogether. [See here for source](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update)

Answer (score 6):

The idiom for "tell React not to do anything" is "return the previous state". It's up to React's internal management to determine that there are no actual changes to the DOM, and nothing will be visible to the user. In particular, the default `shouldComponentUpdate` will return false if the two objects are identical.

So the only thing you need is:

`return previousState`;

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cancel setting state. You can use [shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) to decide if component should update or not.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the states outside of this.setState and depending on whether it's changed or not, fire this.setState?